# Cannot remove textarea margin-bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea which nested inside a div. Why has the textarea a kind of bottom-margin. How can I remove it?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBYXL/)

HTML

```
<form id="form">


    <div class="message_content">
        <textarea name="content" type="text" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
    </div>

</form>
```

CSS

```
  .message_content {
 height:auto;
 overflow: auto;
 background: red;
 }

 .message_content textarea {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: grey;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0;
 resize: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add in your `textarea`:

`display: inherit;`

**css**

```
.message_content textarea {
font-size: 14px;
color: grey;
height: 200px;
margin: 0;
resize: none;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inherit; /*Add this*/
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBYXL/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following CSS code :

```
.message_content {
    height:auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background: red;
}

.message_content textarea {
    display: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: grey;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    resize: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add you code in .message_content textarea `display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

Give `height` to `.message_content` and `100%` to `textarea`.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XBYXL/4/) here.